# Error: invalid_client unknown client for a simple POST request

Tags: python, python-requests, stocktwits

I'm trying to access the API for Stocktwits and get the above error when I post a request to the server. Below is my code:

```
data = [
  ('client_id', '<client id>'),
  ('response_type', 'code'),
  ('redirect_uri', 'http://example.com'),
  ('scope', 'read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,follow_users,follow_stocks')
]

d = requests.post('https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize', data=data)
print d.text
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? The client_id is what I got after registering my app domain with Stocktwits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this error would come back to you is if you are sending in a `client_id` that doesn't exist. Not much help to be given here, you just have to be sure the client_id is the correct one that is given to you after registering a StockTwits app.

Comment: Hi - yes, I've used the client_id that was given to me after registering my app with Stocktwits. That's what is confusing to me. Is there any way this would work if I can get new client_id by re-registering the app?

Comment: Update: I've re-registered the app to get new client_id but the post request still throws the same error. Kinda clueless as to why.

Comment: I can look it up. What is your stocktwits username? You can give it to me here or email me at eric@stocktwits.com

Comment: Just a quick note as to what was happening. I was a little naive to pass the client_id with the brackets "<" and ">" which was causing it to not be recognized. Thanks for helping via email, Eric!